# Getting Error : Method Not Allowed while using @FeignClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, feign

- I have three microservice in my project 1) **Hotel service** 2)**Hotel-rating service** 3) **User-service**
- Getting Error "**Method Not Allowed while using @FeignClient**" while calling Hotel-Service through User-Service
- **Dependencies** : Spring Cloud Eureka client/ server FeignClient to call other service.

**User Controller**

```
 @GetMapping("/{userId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
    User user = this.userService.getUser(userId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
@Override

        public User getUser(String userId) {
            User user = this.userRepo.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFounds("user id not found " + userId));

            ResponseEntity<List<Rating>> ratingByUser = this.hotelRating.getRatingByUser(user.getId());// using feighClient
            List<Rating> ratings = ratingByUser.getBody();
            user.setRatings(ratings);
    
    //        get the hotel infromation from hotel service
            List<Rating> collect = ratings.stream().map(userH -> {
    //       
                logger.info("Hotel Id "+ userH.getHotelId());
                ResponseEntity<Hotel> hotelResponse = hotelService.getHotel(userH.getHotelId());
                logger.info("status code ", hotelResponse.getStatusCode());
    
                Hotel hotel = hotelResponse.getBody();
    
    //            set Hotel object to user object
                userH.setHotel(hotel);
                return userH;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
            return user;
        }
```

**HotelService** (*using FeignClient, in Userservice
service*)

```
@Service
@FeignClient(name = "HOTEL-SERVICE")
public interface HotelService {

//    @GetMapping("/hotel/{hotelId}")
//    Hotel getHotel(@PathVariable("hotelId") String hotelId);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/hotel/{hotelId}")
    ResponseEntity<Hotel> getHotel(@PathVariable("hotelId") String hotelId);

//    get All hotel information
    @GetMapping("/hotel/all")
    ResponseEntity<List<Hotel>> getAllHotelList();
}
```

**HotelController** (*UserService will call this Service to get Hotel information* )

```
   @GetMapping("/{hotelId}")
    public  ResponseEntity<Hotel> getHotel(@PathVariable("hotelId") String hotelId){
        Hotel hotel = this.hotelService.getHotel(hotelId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(hotel , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Error** (*get error while calling hotelService*)

```
**feign.FeignException$MethodNotAllowed: [405] during [GET] to [http://HOTEL-SERVICE/hotel/] [HotelService#getHotel(String)]: [{"timestamp":"2023-02-26T16:21:16.604+00:00","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","path":"/hotel/"}]**
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:221) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185) ~[feign-core-11.10.jar:na]
```

**It Work Fine in @Test**

```
@Autowired
    private HotelService hotelService;

 @Test
    void getSingleHotelInfor(){
        ResponseEntity<Hotel> hotel = this.hotelService.getHotel("72db342b-678c-486b-8d37-25b97851cec6");
        System.out.println(hotel.getBody().getName());
    }
```

Comment: hotelId is null and .../hotel/ path is not defined, therefore the mentioned error occured

Comment: hotelId is not null, i have checked.

Comment: Check again - [GET] to [http://HOTEL-SERVICE/hotel/]  in the error log shows the id is not populated. It is therefore hitting a path “/hotel”, which is not a GET.